# Обновление , а не добавление в таблицу

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток, на сайте есть поиск и есть таблица , в которую при нажатии кнопки добавляются записи из ДБ исходя из выбранного параметра в поиске.
Надо чтобы записи в таблице не добавлялись , а обновлялись

Сам код jQuery

```
$('body').on('click', '#search_appartament', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 

$.ajax({    
    url: "/index/index/",       
    type: "post",
    data: $('#form_appartament').serialize(),               
    global: false,
    dataType: "json",
    response:'text',
    cache: false, 
    async: false,
    error: function(req, err){ console.log(err); },
    success: function(data) { 

        $('#del').remove();



        for ( var i=0; i<data.length; i++ ) {

            var img = '';
            for ( var j=0; j<data[i].id_level; j++ ) {                      
                if ( j<5 ) { img = img + '<img src="/images/star.png" alt="Star" />'; } else {
                             img = img + '<strong style="font-size:18px;"> DLX</strong>'; break; }                          
            }  

            var strPost = '<tr>'
                +'<td>'
                    +'<a href="/catalog/nedvizhimost/'+data[i].alias+'">'
                        +'<img src="/images/catalog/tmb/'+data[i].preview+'" alt="" width="193" height="147" />'
                    +'</a>'
                +'</td>'
                +'<td valign="top" style="padding-left: 16px;">'
                    +'<div class="ar_levels">'+img+'</div>'
                    +'<div class="ar_title">'
                        +'<a href="/catalog/nedvizhimost/'+data[i].alias+'">'+data[i].name+'</a>'
                    +'</div>'
                    +'<div class="ar_desc">'+data[i].textarea.substr(0,232)+'...</div>'
                    +'<div class="ar_more">'
                        +'<a href="/catalog/nedvizhimost/'+data[i].alias+'">Подробнее &gt;</a>'
                    +'</div>'
                +'</td>'
            +'</tr>';                               

            $('#tabl > tbody').append(strPost);

        }

    }

});
```

});

[Вот сам поиск](http://mrdt.ru/articles/main/poisk-appartamentov/)

Comment: Вам опустошить контейнер надо я так понял а начале success - `$('#tabl > tbody').empty();`

Comment: Или заместо append использовать html  $('#tabl > tbody').html(strPost);

Comment: Спасибо , заработало!!!!

Comment: @Saveliy, в примере цикл, замена на `html()` тут будет показывать  только последний результат. 
А вообще вставлять каждый объект в цикле нагрузно. Правильнее создать `strPosts` перед циклом, в цикле ее плюсовать, и после цикла уже `.append()`

Comment: @Artem Gorlachev Не очень внимательно посмотрел контекст. Разумеется лучше сконкатенировать строку а потом сделать разовую вставку или с предварительной очисткой через empty а потом append как вы писали выше или html. И не внутри цикла.